# HTML/CSS: move contents with scrolling witin table element

Tags: html, css

I'm building a table that will have 1,2,4,8,16...256 columns.(for genealogy overview)
I want the first row to span the 256 columns, the second row 128 etc...

off course I will have to scroll left and right. what I want is that the table cell value scrolls with when the cell is visible. I already have tried the div within **td**, but it does not work. I have added the table as example.
As you can see, the value is not always visible. What I want is for that value (like in row 1) to be visible wherever one is scrolling left and right....

```css
 table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
 text-align:Center
}
```

```html
<html xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td colspan=256>me</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=128>parent 1</td><td colspan=128>parent 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=64>Grandparent 1</td><td colspan=64>Grandparent 2</td><td colspan=64>Grandparent3</td><td colspan=64>Grandparent4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=32>person 1</td><td colspan=32>person 2</td>
<td colspan=32>person 3</td><td colspan=32>person 4</td>
<td colspan=32>person 1</td><td colspan=32>person 2</td>
<td colspan=32>person 3</td><td colspan=32>person 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=16>person 1</td><td colspan=16>person 2</td>
<td colspan=16>person 3</td><td colspan=16>person 4</td>
<td colspan=16>person 1</td><td colspan=16>person 2</td>
<td colspan=16>person 3</td><td colspan=16>person 4</td>
<td colspan=16>person 1</td><td colspan=16>person 2</td>
<td colspan=16>person 3</td><td colspan=16>person 4</td>
<td colspan=16>person 1</td><td colspan=16>person 2</td>
<td colspan=16>person 3</td><td colspan=16>person 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
<td colspan=8>person 1</td><td colspan=8>person 2</td>
<td colspan=8>person 3</td><td colspan=8>person 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
<td colspan=4>person 1</td><td colspan=4>person 2</td>
<td colspan=4>person 3</td><td colspan=4>person 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
<td colspan=2>person 1</td><td colspan=2>person 2</td>
<td colspan=2>person 3</td><td colspan=2>person 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using JQuery you can use this as a template to build your code, I created a while loop which will run and insert the td tags, with the `colspan` reducing by half on each iteration. I removed some CSS because the rendered element was not looking good, please use this code to build your usecase!

```js
var start = 256;
var step = start;
var elem = $('table#genealogy');
var html= `<tr><td colspan="FILLERNUMBER">
<div id="rel"> 
<div id="center">
<p>me<br>o</p>
</div>
</div>
</td><td colspan="REMAININGNUMBER"></td></tr>`
while(step > 1){
  if(start-step === 0){
    var output = html.replace("FILLERNUMBER", step).replace("REMAININGNUMBER", '\" style=\"display:none;\"');
  }else{
    var output = html.replace("FILLERNUMBER", step).replace("REMAININGNUMBER", start-step);
  }
  elem.append(output);
  step = step/2;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
 text-align:Center
}

#center
{
 left: 50%;
} 
#rel
{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head lang="nl"> 
  
</head>
<body><!--style="width:100%"-->

<table style="width:100%" id="genealogy">


<table>
```